# Adding a command to Vim

Tags: vim

I finally decided to try out [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29), as I am getting increasingly frustrated by GUI editors. So far, I'm loving it, but I can't find any help for a issue I'm having...

I am trying to map the command `:Pyrun` to `:!python %` in Vim using `cmap`. The mapping shows up fine if I type `:cmap`. However, on typing `:Pyrun`, I get this error message:

> Not an editor command: Pyrun.

Here is what I'm trying in .vimrc:

```
:autocmd FileType python :cmap Pyrun<cr> !python %<cr>
:autocmd FileType python :cmap Intpyrun<cr> !python -i %<cr>
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Read the 42 pdf in this url http://zmievski.org/talks/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I would try something like this in your .vimrc or your ftplugin/python_ft.vim

```
command Pyrun execute "!python %"
command Intpyrun execute "!python -i %"
```

Then `:Pyrun` and `:Intpyrun` should work

You could then map a function key to each

```
map <F5> :Pyrun<CR>
map <F6> :Intpyrun<CR>
```

Comment: to add the buffer-local command, use `:command -buffer`...`:command -b` does not work

Answer (score 30):

I personally prefer another approach. First create a function receiving the command arguments and then create a command to call the function:

```
fun! DoSomething( arg ) "{{{
    echo a:arg
    " Do something with your arg here
endfunction "}}}

command! -nargs=* Meh call DoSomething( '<args>' )
```

So it would be like

```
fun! Pyrun( arg ) "{{{
    execute '!python ' . expand( '%' )
endfunction "}}}

command! -nargs=* Pyrun call Pyrun( '<args>' )
```

But, there's a better way to do it in Vim. Use makeprg:

```
makeprg=python\ %
```

Just type `:make` to run your current Python file. Use `:copen` to show error list.

Comment: Sounds like a more scalable approach. I will probably do something like this if I need more than one command executed.

Comment: Is there a benefit to defining the function `Pyrun` and the command `Pyrun` to take arguments when these are not actually used? I'd expect either to pass `arg` along to the python script, or have none and use `-nargs=0` (which is also the default) in the `command!` line...

Answer (score 12):

G'day,

Similar to karoberts answer, I prefer the more direct:

```
:map <F9> :!python %<CR>
```

If my script is creating some output I also like to capture it in a temp file and then autoread that files content into another buffer, e.g.

```
:map <F9> :!python % 2>&1 \| tee /tmp/results
```

I then set autoread by entering `:set autoread` and opening the results file in another buffer

```
:split /tmp/results<CR>
```

Then I can easily see the results of the run in the buffer that auto refreshes when the results file is updated by running the script under development.

HTH

cheers,

Answer (score 0):

With new LUA api:

```
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command('Hello', 'echo "Hello World!"', {})
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command('HelloLua', function ()
    print('Hello LUA!')
end, {})
```

[NeoVIM API reference](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#api-command)