# Create a new Vim command to execute several built-in commands?

Tags: vim

For example, I want to create a command called `Mycmd` (the first letter need to be capitalized). Whey I'm in normal mode and type `:Mycmd`, I hope the following command series can be done:

```
:set ts=2
:set sw=2
:set sws=2
:set expandtab
```

I found `command` syntax seems to be on the right track, for example: [[StackOverflow]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001190/adding-a-command-to-vim), but I couldn't do it with more than two commands (i.e., :set one thing then :set another thing).

I don't really consider `nmap` since I want to create my command instead of mapping to a hot key, though `nmap` allows to execute commands at the same time (e.g., `nmap <F7> :set ts=2<enter>:set sw=2<enter>`)

Comment: Just curious: Why do you need it, storing these settings in .vimrc file is not enough for you?

Comment: Good question, because I'm working on another project which use a separate indent style, not possible to separate based on file names, so that's why I was thinking to create a command so that I can switch to another indent settings.

Comment: P.S., it seems one solution is that I make a macro and wire the new command to this macro, but still looking for a neater solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
command Mycmd set ts=2 | set sw=2 | set sws=2 | set expandtab
```

`|` is used to separate commands inside any Vim script.

Or even simpler:

```
command Mycmd set ts=2 sw=2 sws=2 expandtab
```

To change the settings, then show the changes:

```
command Mycmd set ts=2 sw=2 sws=2 expandtab ts? sw? sws? et?
```

To map it:

```
nnoremap <silent> _I :Mycmd<cr>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is:

```
command! Mycmd setlocal ts=2 sw=2 sws=2 expandtab
```

What you (and everyone) need is [Editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org/).